# Javascript How to find the intersect of two quadraticCurveTo functions

Tags: javascript, math

Exactly what the title says. I am trying to create the illusion of 3d using 2 quadratic curves crossing a circle perpendicularly in order to show it being curved either in or out. I think that this illusion would be completed if I could just figure out how to find the intersect and make a smaller circle around that point. 
[What I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqR0i.png)

Edit: Since it seems too difficult to do this is there a function that I can use to replace the quadraticCurve to function that starts at a point, passes through a point, and ends at a point?

Comment: Welcome, to stackoverflow. Please provide some additional context, such as what have you tried so far, and what libraries (if any) you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You essentially have a system of two quadratic equations in two variables, namely the parameters for your two curves. You could eliminate one of the variables using e.g. [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant), then check all possible choices for one parameter to see whether it and the corresponding values for the other parameter are real and in the [0,1] range. The resultant will be a polynomial of degree 4, so you'll need quite a bit of math to solve that although it is possible to do this without resorting to numerical methods.

If all of this sounds too complicated, and you *know* that there will be only a single point of intersection, I'd suggest some bisection approach instead. Translate one of your quadratic curves to implicit form (perhaps using resultants again to eliminate the parameter). That way you can easily check which side of the curve a given point is on. Then bisect on the parameters of the other curve: start with both endpoints, pick a point in between, and then use it insetad of one of the endpoints in such a way that the two points you hold are always on different sides of the other curve. Proceed until your parameter range is sufficiently small.

You could also convert both your curves to implicit form, and then follow [these instructions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/425412/35416) to compute the for points of intersection between two quadrics in a way that only requires computing roots of cubic polynomials, not quartic ones.

Comment: Um...I'm a highschool freshman. I really don't understand anything you said heh. Is there no mathematical equation to find the intersection based on the variables given? Also would all this math be too taxing to do 4 times at 50 frames per second?

Comment: @InvincibleBlaze: There are equations, but they look like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_matrix#Definition) and result in several screens full of formula if I feed them to my computer algebra system. So it would be better to write (several screens full of) algorithm to do this job. I won't do this work here for you. On modern hardware I'd say 200 such computations per second should be feasible.